# How to make a background process foreground in Linux

Tags: linux, stdout

I started a program in Linux with the command `screen -d -m sbt run`. How to make it again to foreground or at least view it's logs and prints? My application is a dev mode play framework web application written in java and I want to see the system.out.prints

Comment: You can check this Q/A how to manage STDOUT of running process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process

Comment: i asked my question in stackoverflow , it was deleted and they sendd me here , now get to go back there ? + this is not what im looking for i already seen that